# How to make rtl8192cu drivers work on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, driver

I've bought a Sitecom N300 USB WiFi adapter because my desktop computer does not have a wireless card. On the box it said that it worked on linux and at first glance it seemed so, but connection is discontinued, it works for one minute and then it doesn't.

Ubuntu does recognize it. By running `ls usb` it output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 04b3:3025 IBM Corp. NetVista Full Width Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0df6:0077 Sitecom Europe B.V. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I looked on the net how to configure `0df6:0077` and I found out that this wifi dongle uses the Realtek 8192cu drivers which don't work well on linux.

I also find out how to "fix" them on github at [pvaret/rtl81925cu-fixes](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) and after following the instructions it got worst. Now Ubuntu does not see any wifi.

I read that may people succeeded installing the fix but I didn't.

I already reinstalled Ubuntu twice. How can I make it work?

Additional infos:

`sudo lshw -class network` output

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:24:e8:44:eb:26
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=5754-v3.15 ip=192.168.1.113 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:28 memory:fd8f0000-fd8fffff
```

`iwconfig` output

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your computer has secure boot enabled you might run into problems trying to install drivers using dkms - I had this problem at least. The solution was to disable secure boot from bios. The method for doing this will vary according to your motherboard.